# Qt. All functions work in release folder, but not in Program Files

Tags: c++, qt

in my program I have functions to restart program and load / save settings from .ini file. Everything is working in release folder, but when I install it (program is in C://Program Files (x86)):

*When I call restart function

```
QProcess::startDetached(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
exit(0);
```

Application is terminating itself, but new instance is not started...

*or When I call save settings to .ini file

```
QSettings setting(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "//config//settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
setting.sync();
setting.beginGroup("/Example");
setting.setValue("/Example1", 
setting.endGroup();
```

When I run App first time, usually It saves once, but next times Settings is not saved, settings.ini, or any other .ini file which I'm trying to save looks like 'locked' and I can't save it even through notepad... But If I run App with Administrator permissions everything is working (Restart still don't)

//Edit: I'have checked this on desktop, It works. On another partition (D://) it doesn't work.

In this moment other functions work normally. Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: You can't save data to the program files folder in Windows if UAC is enabled. This is by design, it's not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need admin rights to create a file to Program Files in latest windows. Try install it somewhere else and check if it still fails

Comment: Files are creating with installation.
I'have tryed to install it on Desktop, D, E partition. It works. Could I make it workable in ProgramFiles?

Comment: nope it is not possible to save files to programFiles without admin rights , expect if you disable UAC of windows which of course is not recommended

Comment: Ok, what's about restarting?

Comment: Please read my question once again... I have also problem with restart function.

Comment: even when restarting ,  you have to always run the application as Administrator in order to work from programfiles folder. There isn't a permament way to set the "run as administration" command

Answer (score 1):

By default you need administrator rights to write inside Program Files.

Your application should use instead the path `C:\ProgramData` (assuming `C:` system drive), to save files intended to be shared with all users (eventually creating a directory inside with the company / application's name). The location should be accessed by using the environment variables `ProgramData` or `AllUsersProfile`.

Or, to save settings / data separately for each user, you could use these environment variables to access the intended directory:

- `AppData` (expanding to e.g. `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming`) - user profile specific data
- `LocalAppData` (expanding to e.g. `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local`) - machine specific data

`getenv` function can be used for reading an environment variable.

Comment: Ok, what's about restarting?

Comment: Can you check if `startDetached` returns `true` (for success)? And also the return of `applicationFilePath`.

Comment: I've tryed if (QProcess::startDetached(QApplication::applicationFilePath()));   QMessageBox::information(this, "Test", "True"); and in ProgramFiles it returns "True", but I'm not sure if I made it in right way. applicationFilePath returns right path.

Comment: See also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html to find the locations in a platform-independent way.